# Interpolate data in R

Tags: r

I have these data for each individual (`id`).

I would like to interpolate data (`hr`, `fr`, `relVO2`, `percent_relVO2`) for each individual according their respective interpolated 25, 50 and 75 % of `percent_power`.

Thank you very much all for your help,

```
            id power  training     hr    fr percent_power    relVO2 percent_relVO2 group temps
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25    linear  88.75 22.75      21.73913  8.797619       49.34068   CHD     1
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40    linear  93.25 23.00      34.78261  9.758929       54.73210   CHD     1
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55    linear  99.75 22.75      47.82609 11.324405       63.51193   CHD     1
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70    linear 109.75 23.00      60.86957 12.800595       71.79102   CHD     1
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85    linear 118.75 22.75      73.91304 14.273810       80.05341   CHD     1
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100    linear 127.00 26.00      86.95652 16.020833       89.85144   CHD     1
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115    linear 135.75 28.00     100.00000 17.830357      100.00000   CHD     1
8  AC12-PRD-C2    25    linear  84.25 20.50      17.24138  7.974646       40.10378   CHD     2
9  AC12-PRD-C2    40    linear  89.25 20.50      27.58621  8.649764       43.49889   CHD     2
10 AC12-PRD-C2    55    linear  96.25 22.25      37.93103  9.852594       49.54781   CHD     2
11 AC12-PRD-C2    70    linear 102.25 21.75      48.27586 12.529481       63.00964   CHD     2
12 AC12-PRD-C2    85    linear 110.75 22.25      58.62069 13.923939       70.02224   CHD     2
13 AC12-PRD-C2   100    linear 118.25 23.00      68.96552 15.931604       80.11861   CHD     2
14 AC12-PRD-C2   115    linear 129.25 24.75      79.31034 17.765330       89.34025   CHD     2
15 AC12-PRD-C2   130    linear 136.25 26.50      89.65517 18.552476       93.29874   CHD     2
16 AC12-PRD-C2   145    linear 147.50 29.75     100.00000 19.885024      100.00000   CHD     2
17 AL13-PRD-C1    25 nonlinear  69.50 16.50      19.23077  7.733918       41.36691   CHD     1
18 AL13-PRD-C1    40 nonlinear  73.00 17.50      30.76923  8.754386       46.82515   CHD     1
19 AL13-PRD-C1    55 nonlinear  83.25 15.50      42.30769 10.000000       53.48764   CHD     1
20 AL13-PRD-C1    70 nonlinear  93.75 16.00      53.84615 11.514620       61.58899   CHD     1
21 AL13-PRD-C1    85 nonlinear 104.50 16.00      65.38462 13.444444       71.91117   CHD     1
22 AL13-PRD-C1   100 nonlinear 114.25 19.25      76.92308 15.748538       84.23522   CHD     1
23 AL13-PRD-C1   115 nonlinear 125.25 20.75      88.46154 16.970760       90.77260   CHD     1
24 AL13-PRD-C1   130 nonlinear 136.25 24.75     100.00000 18.695906      100.00000   CHD     1
25 AL13-PRD-C2    25 nonlinear  60.25 15.75      15.62500  6.911408       30.83378   CHD     2
26 AL13-PRD-C2    40 nonlinear  63.25 14.25      25.00000  7.666869       34.20411   CHD     2
27 AL13-PRD-C2    55 nonlinear  72.75 15.75      34.37500 10.024272       44.72117   CHD     2
28 AL13-PRD-C2    70 nonlinear  79.00 15.50      43.75000 11.471481       51.17759   CHD     2
29 AL13-PRD-C2    85 nonlinear  88.25 16.00      53.12500 13.962379       62.29020   CHD     2
30 AL13-PRD-C2   100 nonlinear  99.00 16.75      62.50000 15.767597       70.34380   CHD     2
31 AL13-PRD-C2   115 nonlinear 107.00 18.00      71.87500 16.962985       75.67677   CHD     2
32 AL13-PRD-C2   130 nonlinear 118.50 21.00      81.25000 18.822816       83.97401   CHD     2
33 AL13-PRD-C2   145 nonlinear 128.25 24.25      90.62500 20.785801       92.73146   CHD     2
34 AL13-PRD-C2   160 nonlinear 142.50 29.00     100.00000 22.415049      100.00000   CHD     2
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`?approx`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html)?

Comment: *How* would you like to interpolate?  Linearly, I assume, but that's not the only option...

Comment: Yes, linearly please.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the ``mutate`` function but in vain.

Answer (score 2):

### base R

```r
byout <- by(dat[,c("percent_power","hr","fr","relVO2","percent_relVO2")], dat["id"],
            FUN = function(z) data.frame(lapply(z, function(a) approx(a, x=z[[1]], xout=c(25, 50, 75))$y)))
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, nm) transform(x, id = nm), byout, names(byout)))
#               percent_power        hr       fr    relVO2 percent_relVO2          id
# AC12-PRD-C1.1            25  89.87500 22.81250  9.037947       50.68854 AC12-PRD-C1
# AC12-PRD-C1.2            50 101.41666 22.79167 11.570436       64.89178 AC12-PRD-C1
# AC12-PRD-C1.3            75 119.43750 23.02083 14.419396       80.86992 AC12-PRD-C1
# AC12-PRD-C2.1            25  88.00000 20.50000  8.480984       42.65011 AC12-PRD-C2
# AC12-PRD-C2.2            50 103.66667 21.83333 12.761891       64.17841 AC12-PRD-C2
# AC12-PRD-C2.3            75 124.66667 24.02083 17.001278       85.49790 AC12-PRD-C2
# AL13-PRD-C1.1            25  71.25000 17.00000  8.244152       44.09603 AL13-PRD-C1
# AL13-PRD-C1.2            50  90.25000 15.83333 11.009747       58.88854 AL13-PRD-C1
# AL13-PRD-C1.3            75 112.62500 18.70833 15.364522       82.18121 AL13-PRD-C1
# AL13-PRD-C2.1            25  63.25000 14.25000  7.666869       34.20411 AL13-PRD-C2
# AL13-PRD-C2.2            50  85.16667 15.83333 13.132080       58.58600 AL13-PRD-C2
# AL13-PRD-C2.3            75 110.83333 19.00000 17.582929       78.44252 AL13-PRD-C2
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    across(c(hr, fr, relVO2, percent_relVO2), ~ approx(cur_data()$percent_power, ., xout = c(25, 50, 75))$y), 
    percent_power = c(25, 50, 75), 
    .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 12 x 6
#    id             hr    fr relVO2 percent_relVO2 percent_power
#    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
#  1 AC12-PRD-C1  89.9  22.8   9.04           50.7            25
#  2 AC12-PRD-C1 101.   22.8  11.6            64.9            50
#  3 AC12-PRD-C1 119.   23.0  14.4            80.9            75
#  4 AC12-PRD-C2  88.0  20.5   8.48           42.7            25
#  5 AC12-PRD-C2 104.   21.8  12.8            64.2            50
#  6 AC12-PRD-C2 125.   24.0  17.0            85.5            75
#  7 AL13-PRD-C1  71.2  17     8.24           44.1            25
#  8 AL13-PRD-C1  90.3  15.8  11.0            58.9            50
#  9 AL13-PRD-C1 113.   18.7  15.4            82.2            75
# 10 AL13-PRD-C2  63.2  14.2   7.67           34.2            25
# 11 AL13-PRD-C2  85.2  15.8  13.1            58.6            50
# 12 AL13-PRD-C2 111.   19    17.6            78.4            75
```

Note that in `dplyr`, the order of calculation matters. If we put the `percent_power=` reassignment *before* `across(...)`, then `approx` will never see the real (more rows) value, it will only see the new (`c(25,50,75)`) value.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat) # setDT(dat) would be more canonical
DT[, c(
    list(percent_power = c(25, 50, 75)), 
    lapply(.SD, function(a) approx(a, x=percent_power, xout=c(25, 50, 75))$y)
  ), by = .(id), .SDcols = c("hr","fr","relVO2","percent_relVO2")]
#              id percent_power        hr       fr    relVO2 percent_relVO2
#  1: AC12-PRD-C1            25  89.87500 22.81250  9.037947       50.68854
#  2: AC12-PRD-C1            50 101.41666 22.79167 11.570436       64.89178
#  3: AC12-PRD-C1            75 119.43750 23.02083 14.419396       80.86992
#  4: AC12-PRD-C2            25  88.00000 20.50000  8.480984       42.65011
#  5: AC12-PRD-C2            50 103.66667 21.83333 12.761891       64.17841
#  6: AC12-PRD-C2            75 124.66667 24.02083 17.001278       85.49790
#  7: AL13-PRD-C1            25  71.25000 17.00000  8.244152       44.09603
#  8: AL13-PRD-C1            50  90.25000 15.83333 11.009747       58.88854
#  9: AL13-PRD-C1            75 112.62500 18.70833 15.364522       82.18121
# 10: AL13-PRD-C2            25  63.25000 14.25000  7.666869       34.20411
# 11: AL13-PRD-C2            50  85.16667 15.83333 13.132080       58.58600
# 12: AL13-PRD-C2            75 110.83333 19.00000 17.582929       78.44252
```

Unlike in dplyr, I can name the new field `percent_power` the same since in the subsequent `lapply`, the ref to `percent_power` is resolved to the original (more values) data, not the new. (This is one area where `mutate` and `data.table`-semantics are very different: in `mutate`, one calculation can refer to a column calculated previously in the same `mutate`, whereas in `data.table` this is not true.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2",  "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2"), power = c(25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L), training = c("linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear",  "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear"), hr = c(88.75, 93.25, 99.75, 109.75, 118.75, 127, 135.75, 84.25, 89.25, 96.25, 102.25, 110.75, 118.25, 129.25, 136.25, 147.5, 69.5, 73, 83.25, 93.75, 104.5, 114.25, 125.25, 136.25, 60.25, 63.25, 72.75, 79, 88.25, 99, 107, 118.5, 128.25, 142.5), fr = c(22.75, 23, 22.75, 23, 22.75, 26, 28, 20.5, 20.5, 22.25, 21.75, 22.25, 23, 24.75, 26.5, 29.75, 16.5, 17.5, 15.5, 16, 16,  19.25, 20.75, 24.75, 15.75, 14.25, 15.75, 15.5, 16, 16.75, 18, 21, 24.25, 29), percent_power = c(21.73913, 34.78261, 47.82609, 60.86957, 73.91304, 86.95652, 100, 17.24138, 27.58621, 37.93103, 48.27586, 58.62069, 68.96552, 79.31034, 89.65517, 100, 19.23077, 30.76923, 42.30769, 53.84615, 65.38462, 76.92308, 88.46154, 100, 15.625, 25, 34.375, 43.75, 53.125, 62.5, 71.875, 81.25, 90.625, 100), relVO2 = c(8.797619, 9.758929, 11.324405, 12.800595, 14.27381, 16.020833, 17.830357, 7.974646, 8.649764, 9.852594,  12.529481, 13.923939, 15.931604, 17.76533, 18.552476, 19.885024, 7.733918, 8.754386, 10, 11.51462, 13.444444, 15.748538, 16.97076, 18.695906, 6.911408, 7.666869, 10.024272, 11.471481, 13.962379, 15.767597, 16.962985, 18.822816, 20.785801, 22.415049), percent_relVO2 = c(49.34068, 54.7321, 63.51193, 71.79102, 80.05341, 89.85144, 100, 40.10378, 43.49889, 49.54781, 63.00964, 70.02224, 80.11861, 89.34025, 93.29874, 100, 41.36691, 46.82515, 53.48764, 61.58899, 71.91117, 84.23522, 90.7726, 100, 30.83378,  34.20411, 44.72117, 51.17759, 62.2902, 70.3438, 75.67677, 83.97401, 92.73146, 100), group = c("CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD", "CHD"), temps = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34"))
```

Comment: Thank you for trying ! Unfortunately, I can't see the interpolated ``25``, ``50``, ``75`` % for each individual.

Comment: The first three rows are the first "user" (id `-C1`), and the first three `percent_power` values are its 25%ile, 50%ile, and 75%ile from the original data.

Comment: Do you mean interpolating on `power`'s 25, 50, 75, onto `percent_power` somehow?

Comment: Ultimately, it may better inform the issue if you have actual interpolated numbers *by hand*, even if you don't know the code to automate it well.

Comment: A valiant effort to be sure, but I suspect the question author wants three rows for each `id` with `percent_power = c(25,50,75)` and the columns `c("hr","fr","relVO2","percent_relVO2")` approximated based on the available values of `percent_power`.

Comment: Yes Ian Campbell, this is exactly what I would like to get.

Comment: Wow, I'm embarrassed, over-complicating things. See the edit (and you can still accept if it works despite being closed :-).